# Open and closing forms on exit in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How do you reload the main form on exit of a secondary form? For example, if frmMain is the main form and you hid that to load another form called GenerateNumbers, then how do you get frmMain back when the user exits GenerateNumbers?

Comment: Do your need move some information from GenerateNumbers form to a Main form on closing?

Comment: No. In this case, each form will have separate purposes with no need to save work. To be more specific, it's a lotto number generator.

Comment: Project + Properties, Application tab, Shutdown mode = When last form closes.  Now you can simply call Show() to display the new form and close a form you don't want to be active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you called the secondary Form with ShowDialog you would then make your Main Form Visible after the Secondary Form returned from the ShowDialog Method.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm2 As Form2 = New Form2
    Me.Hide()
    frm2.ShowDialog()
    Me.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: My code for calling it is this...        Dim frmMain As frmMain()
        Me.Hide()
        GenerateNumbers.Show()
        frmMain = Nothing

Comment: @Brandon Don't set your frmMain to nothing, and use ShowDialog instead of Show. Is frmMain your startup form? if so why are you creating it again?

Comment: @Brandon why you kill a Main form -> frmMain = Nothing?

Comment: @Fabio I found an answer on here somewhere about killing the other form to save memory. I thought that was what I was supposed to do.

Comment: I am a total newbie with vb.net so I am learning from scratch here. That's why I am getting basic things wrong.

Comment: @Brandon I am sure if your application have only 2 forms then don't worry about a memory :) Modern computers have enough of it. Even when your want to use a Main form again later in your application

Comment: @Brandon is your frmMain the startup form ?

Comment: @Mark-Hall It is for now. I will be adding a splash page later as the startup form.

Comment: @Brandon If you go to Project Properties --> Application there is a ComboBox called Splash Screen where you can set Form you are using for the Splash Screen. But back to your question, have you tried what we have suggested and is it working for you?

Comment: I got it working, thank you. I would vote you up if I were allowed. Also, I figured out splash a while back but thank you for that.

Comment: @Brandon You can mark the answer that helped you the most as answered, by selecting the Check Mark.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to add an an event handler to the child form's `Closing` event.  That way, the main form will receive notification when the child form closes and then it can just re-show itself.  For instance:

```
AddHandler frmChild.Closing, AddressOf ChildClosing
frmChild.Show()
Me.Hide()

'....

Private Sub ChildClosing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RemoveHandler CType(sender, Form).Closing, AddressOf ChildClosing
    Me.Show()
End Sub
```

As others have said, if you show the child form with the `ShowDialog` method, that's much easier.  In fact, if you do that, then there's really no reason to hide the main form, you can just pass the main form into the dialog as the owner:

```
frmChild.ShowDialog(Me)
```

Hint: If you don't hide the main form, set the starting position property of the child form to center over the owner.

Alternatively, you could give a reference to the main form so that it can make the main form visible when it is closing, but I'd say that's the least desirable option.

Answer (score 0):

If you show the secondary form as modal, it should be easy. Put this in whatever event you're using to show the secondary form:

```
frmMain.Visible = False
frmGenerateNumbers.ShowDialog()
frmMain.Visible = True
```